# Is it possible to analyze, at compile time, when a map-like structure can be mutated in-place?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, compilation, functional-programming

For simplicity, suppose we extend the lambda calculus with a primitive for maps with string keys. We add two operations: `set map key val` and `get map key`. To actually implement this primitive, we could use a persistent data structure a la Haskell's `Data.Map`, which would give us `O(log(n))` sets and gets.

Suppose we, instead, implemented this structure with hash-tables. `get` would be `O(1)` and `set` would be `O(N)`, as it requires cloning the whole hash-table. **Would it be possible to, during compile-type, analyze all places where it is safe to perform an in-place mutation, replacing `set` by a hidden `mset` operation?**

Comment: Possible, probably yes. But a compiler should be *conservative*: only if the compiler can proof that it is safe, it can use `mset`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sure! I'm wondering what are the generalized scenarios where that is the case.

Comment: For instance, static analysis could detect that the data structure is used _linearly_ (as in linear types / linear logic), and enable that optimization. That would require a full program analysis, though, or at least we need to be able to see all the points where each map could be used.

Comment: @chi I can have full program analysis, but some situations are confusing me. For example, `(let map = {}; inc = \_ -> update (+ 1) 0 map; foo = \f -> (f(0), f(0)) in (foo inc))`. Here, `map` appears only once. But it is used inside `inc`, which is sent to `foo`, which is then used twice. So it isn't enough to check that a variable is only used once, the problem seems to need some more complex analysis. I'd love a resource studying / explaining the problem more concretely!

Comment: @MaiaVictor I am not a linear types expert, but that will not type check I guess. `inc` depends on `map`, so `inc` gets a linear type. `inc` is passed to `foo`, so `foo` must take a linear argument ... but it uses it twice, triggering a type error.

Comment: @chi fair enough! I'm just noticing checking for linearity isn't trivial. The field itself is very big so I'd love if someone with experience in linear types could point to a resource covering this problem! :)